# Build the rotation will gradually slow down according to the given time and position by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a scrolling feature using `background-image` and `background-position-x`. When I click the Roll button, the roll() function will execute.
There will be a starting and ending position. And the X value of `roll.style.backgroundPosition` will depend on the `currentPosition` variable.

I want it to start fast and then slow down until `currentPosition` is equal to `endPosition`. Each time will scroll for about 3-4 seconds.

I tried adjusting the `acceleration` value. However, if you increase the value of this variable, `currentPosition` will likely become a negative number and it will repeat indefinitely. If you decrease the value of this variable, when the speed is not reduced enough, the rotation will stop because `currentPosition` is equal to `endPosition`.

How do I calculate the exact value for the `acceleration` variable based on `duration, startPosition and endPosition` because I want the values of `startPosition and endPosition` to be random each time I execute it.

```
function roll() {
    let startPosition = 1000;
    let endPosition = 5000;
    let currentPosition = startPosition;
    let initialSpeed = 10;
    let duration = 4000;
    let startTime = 0;
    const acceleration = 0.1;
    const roll = document.querySelector('.rotation')

    function updatePosition() {
        startTime += 5
        initialSpeed -= acceleration
        
        initialSpeed = Math.max(initialSpeed, 1);

        currentPosition += initialSpeed;
        if (currentPosition > endPosition) {
            currentPosition = endPosition;
        }

        
        roll.style.backgroundPosition = `${currentPosition}px center`;

        
        if (currentPosition < endPosition) {
            requestAnimationFrame(updatePosition);
        }
    }

    updatePosition();
}
```

Comment: Why not use the power of CSS and drop that code? Like with `keyframes`, `animation`, `transition`, and several other approaches. See for example [Making text slide across the browser window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#making_text_slide_across_the_browser_window)